# I want to display menu items dynamically from database also static in my yii2 frontend

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii-widgets

I just want to display menus from database in yii2 advanced template frontend. Also i have static menus. I am using menu widget

Here is my code

```
           <?php
              echo Menu::widget([
                'options' => ['class' => 'about_content'],
                'items' => CMS::getCMSPages(),
              ]);
            ?>
```

Here CMS::getCMSPages() will get the menus from database. And also i have static menu. So i added into the menu widget like this

```
           <?php
              echo Menu::widget([
                'options' => ['class' => 'about_content'],
                'items' => [[CMS::getCMSPages()],
                     ['label' => 'contact', 'url' => ['site/index']]
                 ]

              ]);
            ?>
```

But this is not working. Someone help me guys

Comment: Can you provide an error output and result array of CMS::getCMSPages() method?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I didn't get any error it simply omit the dynamic menu and showing only static menu. And output of CMS::getCMSPages() is Array ( [0] => Array ( [label] => About us [url] => http://192.168.1.114:1076/ZwxQOnKQdha7SNco.html ) [1] => Array ( [label] => Terms and conditions [url] => http://192.168.1.114:1076/nabmaJDyQ02Ji09j.html ) [2] => Array ( [label] => Contact [url] => http://192.168.1.114:1076/v7tmajLaw4zqPdm6.html ) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CMS::getCMSPages()` method should return properly prepared array of items. Something like this:

```
[
    ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['site/index']],
    ['label' => 'Products', 'url' => ['product/index'],
]
```

Also you should merge items array:

```
<?php
  echo Menu::widget([
    'options' => ['class' => 'about_content'],
    'items' => array_merge(CMS::getCMSPages(), [['label' => 'contact', 'url' => ['site/index']]])
  ]);
?>
```

Comment: But when i put only CMS::getCMSPages() it actually displays the menu items. So it means its in the correct format only. Did i thinking right?

Comment: Thank you   Valery Viktorovsky. Superrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr